# how to make a button on a popup window that closes that popup window

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a popup window with a button that's supposed to close the window. However, it does not work. Here is the code:

```
 winpopup.document.write(<INPUT TYPE = "BUTTON" Value = "Close Window" onClick = "closeWindow();">)

 function closeWindow(){
    winpopup.close();
 }
```

Comment: You cannot give time bounds in SO. This is voluntary help.

Comment: pass a string to `winpopup.document.write`. `winpopup.document.write(<INPUT TYPE = "BUTTON" Value = "Close Window" onClick = "closeWindow();">)` should be `winpopup.document.write('<INPUT TYPE = "BUTTON" Value = "Close Window" onClick = "closeWindow();">')`

Answer (score 0):

Winpopup doesn't have closeWindow() method. Use opener's.

```
function closeWindow(){
    opener.winpopup.close();
}
```